# ie vba submit function does not work

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, passwords, submit

I succeed to pass first password page but in the second page, same submit function does not work and I can not pass the last (third) page. I am trying to take the results of query to Excel. Submit function does not work and it stays on second page. The button name is "submit" also. Same function works on first page but not on second, I am new to this, sorry for if it is a dumb question.

These pages are taken place on local web site so that reason I can not share with you. Thank you in advance

```
Sub GetTable()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieSorgu As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject
Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
Dim SorguForm As HTMLFormElement

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
ieApp.Visible = True

'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
ieApp.Navigate "http://sample/"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop


Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set LoginForm = ieDoc.forms(0)

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
With ieDoc.forms(0)
    .user_name.Value = "admin"
    .pass.Value = "password"
    LoginForm.submit

End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop


'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
ieApp.Navigate "http://sample/rapor_goruntule.php?style=saatlik"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop


Set SorguForm = ieDoc.forms(0)
With ieDoc.forms(0)
    .filtre_kuyruk.Value = "0"  'these values are for query
    .saat_periyot.Value = "01:00:00"
    .mesai_start_sa.Value = "08"
    .mesai_start_dk.Value = "00"
    .mesai_start_sn.Value = "00"
    .mesai_end_sa.Value = "18"
    .mesai_end_dk.Value = "00"
    .mesai_end_sn.Value = "00"
    .filtre_kullanici.Value = "0"
    .bekleme_uzun_sa.Value = "0"
    .bekleme_uzun_dk.Value = "00"
    .bekleme_uzun_sn.Value = "00"
    .islem_kisa_sa.Value = "00"
    .islem_kisa_dk.Value = "00"
    .islem_kisa_sn.Value = "00"
    .islem_uzun_sa.Value = "00"
    .islem_uzun_dk.Value = "00"
    .islem_uzun_sn.Value = "45"
    .work_start_sa.Value = "08"
    .work_start_dk.Value = "00"
    .work_start_sn.Value = "00"
    .work_end_sa.Value = "18"
    .work_end_dk.Value = "00"
    .work_end_sn.Value = "00"
    SorguForm.submit

    End With




Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
'get the table based on the table’s id
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("sampletable")

'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
    Set clip = New DataObject
    clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
    clip.PutInClipboard
    Sheet1.Select
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
    Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
End If

'close 'er up
ieApp.Quit
Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you are not re-assigning the object reference for the Document, so when you try to access the forms collection, you're actually trying to submit the original form again, not the one you want.

Try adding a reassignment before assigning the SoguForm variable :

```
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set SorguForm = ieDoc.forms(0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, still i can not go on next page, submit function does not work. When i close explorer to find what the error is, it gives error on codeSorguForm.submit

    End With




Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Comment: Actually there is no error message , it stuck on  second page, if i close the ie to see the problem is, it passes 'code' sorguform.submit 'code' and it waits on 'code' Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE 'code' with automation error.

Comment: You just said there is an automation error - is there an error code associated with it?  e.g.:  `Run-time error '-2147418094 (80010012)'` or something like that?  That would help to figure out what's causing it to hang.

Comment: Yes but i willfull close ie to see where the code sticks. The error is: run-time error -2147417848 (80010108)
automation error. 
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients   .  It is seen that it passes the code submit and sticks at ReadyState.

Comment: You said you willfully closed internet explorer - if so, that is probably the cause of the error.  If it is not moving past the line you mentioned AND if there is no error unless you close ie, then it is not reaching ready state complete. How long do you wait? Have you given it enough time to complete? You tried adding the line I suggested and you get the same behavior?  Possible then there is more than one form on this page? You may need to loop over the forms collection until you find the form you need. It's hard to help further without seeing the website you're trying to access.

Comment: CBRF23 is correct.  Every time your web page changes you have a new document object in IeApp.  It's a good rule of thumb to not use a variable for the htmldocument, like ieDoc, especially when you plan on using different pages in the same code.  
<BR><BR>
<code>instead of using set ieDoc = ieApp.document</code> 
<BR><BR>
simply use:
<BR><BR>
<code>ieApp.Document.forms(0)</code>